# Typescript: Input display two values (one would not taken into account)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to use an input as read only where I display two values, one would be the name and the other one would be the id.

```
<input readonly type="text" [value]="car.name">
```

I want the car id to be displayed as well

How could I do that?

Comment: is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like: `value="{{car.name}}{{car.id}}"`

[Example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmo6bw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these methods

```
<input [readonly]="true" [value]="car.id: car.name">
```

OR

```
<input [readonly]="true" name="id" [value]="car.id">
<input [readonly]="true" name="name" [value]="car.name">
```

Comment: Have you even tried these solutions? They won't work

Comment: really is `[value]="car.name+' '+car.id"` (to concatenate strings you use `+`) -if one variable is a string and you use a number is concatenated also-